# using condition ng-show when checkbox checked in angualrjs

Tags: angularjs, html

The following is my code, i am trying to exclude the out of stock product by using ng-show. It should show all the products if checkbox is checked only the available product only to be showed.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkStock" value="Exclude Out of Stock" ng-model="exclude" />Exclude Out of Stock
<div class="content">
   <input type="text" ng-model="search" /><br />
   <div ng-show="exclude">
      <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy:'-name' |filter:search" ng-show="product.available">
            {{product.name}} - {{product.price | currency:'₹':3}}
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var myapp = angular.module("MyApp", []);

myapp.controller("ProductController", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.products = [{
            name: 'iPhone7+',
            manufacturer: 'Apple',
            price: 75000,
            available: true
        },
        {
            name: 'iPhone6',
            manufacturer: 'Apple',
            price: 45000,
            available: true
        },
        {
            name: 'Redmi Note 3',
            manufacturer: 'Xiaomi',
            price: 12000,
            available: false
        },
        {
            name: 'Samsung C9 Pro',
            manufacturer: 'Samsung',
            price: 40000,
            available: true
        },
        {
            name: 'Redmi Note 4',
            manufacturer: 'Xiaomi',
            price: 13000,
            available: false
        }
    ];
}]);
```

Please help me.

Comment: how will u know project is out of stock

Comment: why not place the product.available in ng-repeat filter instead than ng-show?

Comment: @ankitgupta in the function i have mentioned **available** property it is either true or false. if it is true product is available. if the checkbox is not available i am getting only the available products.

Comment: can you describe what issue you are facing as your question is not clear??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use more than one ng-show

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkStock" value="Exclude Out of Stock" ng-model="exclude" />Exclude Out of Stock
<div class="content">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search" /><br />
    <div>
        <ul>
          <div ng-show="!exclude">
            <li ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy:'-name' |filter:search">

                   {{product.name}} - {{product.price | currency:'₹':3}}
            </li>
          </div>
          <div ng-show="exclude">
              <li ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy:'-name' |filter:search" ng-show="product.available">

                   {{product.name}} - {{product.price | currency:'₹':3}}
            </li>
          </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

an alternative would be to use ng-if and ng-else, but then the div will be generated on condition and with ng-show both will be generated but only visible on condition.

Comment: thanks for your help. it solved my problem but  you can't add div tag inside <ul>. I tried to put the <div> tags outside it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this within your `<li>` tag

```
<li ng-repeat="product in products | 
               orderBy:'-name' | 
               filter: {products : {available: 'true'}}">
```

Comment: do check if true should have quotation or not